# Is this a CSS bug or am i completely blind?

Tags: jquery, html, css

During the build of my project i was making a page to edit user credentials.
Now, when i added css to it in the stylesheet(As i did with all my html)
it simply refused to work!
Not border, not margins not anything!

This is the HTML.

```
 <div id="EditDetails" class="textfont UserPageWindows">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Edit credentials</p>
      5125125125125<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
         5125125125125
 </div>
```

CSS

```
div.UserPageWindows{
min-width:80%;
margin-top:190px;
border: solid;
border-top:none;
border-bottom:5px;
}
```

The border is messed up.
What am i doing wrong?
I've done this tens of times in this project so far, and it worked perfect!

This is how the border looks in that div:

[image: This is what happens]

As opposed to the picture, this is how it should look like
http://jsfiddle.net/qepybz9L/

Comment: can you make a working fiddle where we can see the issue first hand?

Comment: [center tag not supported in html5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)  just something you should maybe note

Comment: @Banana what's a fiddle? How do i do it?

Comment: @gerdi it doesn't concern me. been working with it all this time.

Comment: a fiddle can be created [Here](http://jsfiddle.net), or you can make a code snippet by editting your question and clicking the "Insert snippet" button (or Ctrl+M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work as desired? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/bv60kosg/4).

```
function ShowWindow(el) {
    $("#UserPageMain").fadeOut(150);
    $(el).fadeIn(150);
}
```

Concerning your CSS issue, there's a lot to note.

1. You want to display a border, but you have only defined a border on specific elements. The problem is that those elements are *empty* and subsequently don't have a width and/or height which means that a border applied to that element won't be visible either. You can see this illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/bv60kosg/3/).
2. Try to refrain from inline CSS. There's a lot that you can put in a serpate CSS file. This will allow you to keep a good overview.
3. I'd advise against using the deprecated `center` tags.
4. Avoid stacking `br` tags. If you need a lot of whitespace, use `margin` instead.
5. When posting code to StackOverflow, keep in mind that the tongue of communication is *English* - even if we're not all native speakers, it *is* an international language. This means that you ought to translate your code at least a bit so that it's clear what you want it to do.
6. Additionally, only post the relevant code for your case.
7. If relevant, as it is in your case, post [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a working example so that we can see what's going wrong. A playground to debug, if you will.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. it all the same. the border is not working correctly, nor the margin top.

Comment: @YuvalRoth The problem is that you only applied a border to empty elements. See my edit.

Comment: But the thing is, i added the numbers and stuff and as you can see in the picture, it doesn't work like normal border would do...

Comment: @YuvalRoth If that's the case, make a fiddle to show your problem. In the fiddle that I made, your problem doesn't occur - or it isn't clear to me at all what you mean. You are the one asking the question, so do your very best to explain it to us. We are simply trying to help, only if it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: This is how it should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/qepybz9L/ yet, in the picture, it's completely off.

Comment: @YuvalRoth What what should look like? Again, it isn't clear what you are asking. Now nothing is visible because you are using zero-opacity and `display: none`. What do you want to display, and when. You earlier said that you needed to display borders, but I don't see any borders in your example.

Comment: I quickly changed that, clearly not quickly enough, but i edited the link, look again.

Comment: @YuvalRoth So that last fiddle that you posted is *what* you want, or what you *don't* want?

Comment: It's what i want, as opposed to the picture in the OP, where the border is messed up.

Comment: @YuvalRoth That's probably because you are setting the div to `inline` in jQuery. If you take a look at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/bv60kosg/4), and click the button, you'll see that my case doesn't have this problem. That's because I don't set it to `inline`. I simply fade the div in with `fadeIn()` which automatically results in `display:block` - which is what you need.